# Autocomplete search word in vim

Tags: vim, autocomplete

How to autocomplete a search word in Vim?

I've the following piece of code and I want to search for the word `pgnExists_f`.

```
if(hj1939stack->pgnArray[index] == newPgn)
{
  /* newPgn already exists in the pgnArray */
  pgnExists_f = TRUE;
}
```

In the search command I pressed TAB after typing pgn hoping that the word would autocomplete to pgnExists_f. But, what followed pgn was `^I`.

`/pgn[TAB]` resulted in

```
/pgn^I
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there are ways.

- this would be the common way, move your cursor on the word `pgnExists_f`, then press `*` or `#`
- using command-line window. In normal mode press `q/` then `i` enter insert mode, type `pgn`, then `ctrl-n` or `ctrl-p` you will see the popup, you can select the word you want to search.

Comment: I know about these two. But, I was looking for a way in search command itself. Using arrow marks or something instead of [TAB]. Thanks anyway

Comment: Can you answer this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32069492/open-previous-or-next-buffer-in-vim

Comment: @SagarJain AFAIK, no built-in way to do what you want.

Comment: @SagarJain `q/` **is** a search command and it accomplishes your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [plugin SearchComplete](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=474) available, that allows this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be achieved using a `cmap` which inserts the return of a function:

```
function! SearchCompletions()
    return "SearchCompletion"
endfunction

cnoremap <Tab> <c-r>=SearchCompletions()<cr>
```

Now pressing `Tab` in the command line will insert the text "SearchCompletion". 
The problem now is to write a SearchCompletions() function which can search ahead for matches in the current buffer. This shouldn't be too difficult, but the question is how slow it will be.

The other problem is that the mapping works whenever the cursor is on the command line, not just the search prompt. I don't know how to restrict it further.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this plugin:

https://github.com/vim-scripts/sherlock.vim

```
By default, it use <C-Tab> for forward completion, and <C-S-Tab> for backward completion.

For example:
:%s/tes<C-Tab> list all word which begin with 'tes' after current cursor position;
:%s/tes<C-S-Tab> list all word which begin with 'tes' before current cursor position;
/tes<C-Tab> list all word which begin with 'tes' after current cursor position;
/tes<C-S-Tab> list all word which begin with 'tes' before current cursor position;
?tes<C-Tab> list all word which begin with 'tes' after current cursor position;
?tes<C-S-Tab> list all word which begin with 'tes' before current cursor position;

In ':' mode, completion is available only after a '/'.

When the right string is in command line, you can:
1) Validate it with <Enter>, or type <Esc> to go away from command line if you are in '?' or '/' mode;
2) Validate it with <Enter> or '/', or type <Esc> to go away from command line if you are in ':' mode.

You can override the default mapping with something like that in your .vimrc:
cnoremap <Whatever you want here> <C-\>esherlock#completeBackward()<CR>
cnoremap <Whatever you want here> <C-\>esherlock#completeForward()<CR>
```