# How do I open previously opened buffer in Vim?

Tags: vim, buffer

How to open a previously opened buffer in Vim?

I've 4 buffers, say buf1 to buf4.

Currently I've opened buf1 and then I open buf3 executing `:b3`.

Now, how do I go back to buf1 (the previously opened buffer) without executing `:b1`?

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> will go to buf2, the previous buffer in the list.

Comment: I would suggest you look at the following related post: [vim, switching between files rapidly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16082991/438329). In particular the part referring to using `:b {partial-name}` (there is a nice picture too!).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
:b#
```

Opens the previously opened buffer.

Repetitive use of the command toggles between the buffers.

Thanks to Related questions on this site!

Comment: Alternatively, `<C-^>` (or `<C-6>` on some keyboards).

Comment: @romainl: Cool. This works on my keyboard. Is it keyboard specific or _vimrc specific?

Comment: Sweet. Just goes to show that there's always something new to learn about vim. I've been content to use :bn and :bp for next and previous buffers respectively, but this could be handy in many situations.

Comment: MRU buffers! The `cd -` of Vim :) (I've been searching for this for a while)